# SVG frozen in GitHub README

Tags: github, svg, markdown

I put [Platane/snk](https://github.com/Platane/snk) in my [GitHub README](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/managing-your-profile-readme) this way:

```
[![Snk](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegoborba25/diegoborba25/output/github-contribution-grid-snake-dark.svg)](https://github.com/Platane/snk)
```

And it works! But I changed the code to [specify the theme](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to):

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" srcset="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegoborba25/diegoborba25/output/github-contribution-grid-snake-dark.svg" />
    <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" srcset="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegoborba25/diegoborba25/output/github-contribution-grid-snake.svg" />
    <img alt="github-snake" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegoborba25/diegoborba25/output/github-contribution-grid-snake.svg"/>
</picture>
```

And it almost works too, but I noticed that, with this syntax, sometimes the snake gets frozen and I need to refresh the page for it to run properly.

Why does it happen? Did using the HTML syntax make it slower?